# Cast string to most fitting type

Tags: go, types, casting

I'm aware that using the `strconv` package, one can parse a string to whatever type they need. However, with the program I'm making, I won't know the optimal type of the variable I need to parse at runtime. Is there a better way to do this than the one I have? (My code is ugly, terrible, and awful. I *really* want to figure out a better solution.)

#### relevant code

```
import(
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
)

type object interface{}

func parse(raw string,block int) object{
    if block==0{
        if raw=="true"{
            return true
        }else if raw=="false"{
            return false
        }else{
            parse(raw,block+1)
        }
    }else if block==1{
        res,err:=strconv.ParseFloat(raw,64)
        if err!=nil{parse(raw,block+1)}
        return res
    }else if block==2{
        res,err:=strconv.ParseInt(raw,10,64)
        if err!=nil{parse(raw,block+1)}
        return res
    }
    return raw
}
```

edit: using the `object` type blocks me from using the returned value in it's type, so that needs to go, too.

Comment: Off the top of my head, although I find that I am having to invent a use case for what it appears you're trying to do above, I would suggest something like: switch on what you're calling "raw" here; then call a func depending the result of the switch and return whatever type is appropriate for your case.

Comment: Oh wait. what about passing in and returning an interface{} and then switching on the type after the return?

Comment: Are the incoming types restricted to bool, int and float? You should return the empty interface type; `interface{}` from `parse`. Go is not like Java or C# where you have a base class of `Object` that everything inherits from. Instead you have an empty interface that all types implement. In the scope where you called `parse` you can use a type switch/type assertions to get the concrete type out of the `interface{}`.

Comment: Probably the whole notion of "optimal type" is misleading: If you do not know the type you cannot process it any further (except type switches).

Comment: @Volker it's definite that the incoming type is `string`, thus I can parse

Comment: @Emilia I know this question is a little old and likely you've handled the problem and moved on but I improved the answer, so hopefully something of it is (more) useful to you now.

Answer (score -1):

## Edit

*The original example was correct but wasn't all that helpful, and it didn't satisfy the OP's requirements. I've since updated the answer so that it works in the given context... and I hope it is also helpful.*

You can return an interface{} and then switch on the return type, something like this:

```
package main

import "strconv"

func parse(raw string, block int) interface{} {
    if block == 0 {
        if raw == "true" || raw == "false" {
            if ok, err := strconv.ParseBool(raw); err == nil {
                return ok
            }
        } 
        return parse(raw, block+1)

    } else if block == 1 {
        if res, err := strconv.ParseInt(raw, 10, 64); err == nil {
            return res
        }
        return parse(raw, block+1)

    } else if block == 2 {
        if res, err := strconv.ParseFloat(raw, 64); err == nil {
            return res
        }
        return parse(raw, block+1)
    }
    return raw
}

func main() {
    a := parse("10.1", 0)
    switch a.(type) {
    case bool:
        //do something with a.(bool))
    case float64:
        //do something with a.(float64))
    case int64:
        //do something with a.(int64))
    case string:
        // do something with a.(string)
    }
}
```

Notable differences between this and your original example:

- You have to return that semi-recursive function call, not merely call it, else you eventually return raw unless your first case (`block == 0`) returns.
- It is necessary to check `ParseInt()` before `ParseFloat()` as an int can always satisfy the conditions of a float, not the other way around however.
- Unless you need methods on the return type you can simply return interface{}, and there is no need to declare a type.
- And finally, for no other reason than style, I opted for returning on `err == nil` vs. calling `parse(raw, block+1)` on `err != nil`; ultimately either get the same result.